# Display dialog box on top of Phone App : Android

Tags: android

I am looking to display a dialog box on top of the Android Native Phone app when there is an outgoing call made.
I am able to create the dialog, but it is not visible on TOP of the Phone App.

I have tried :
The suggestion at : [Android, how to bring a Task to the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919616/android-how-to-bring-a-task-to-the-foreground/18197545#18197545)

Have set the following in the Manifest File

```
        <activity
        android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dialog"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

Phone state listener :

```
public void onCallStateChanged (int state, String incomingNumber)
        {
            if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
                Log.i("PHONESTATE","RINGING");
                //Incoming call handling
            }
            if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {

                Log.i("PHONESTATE","OFFHOOK" + context.toString());
                Intent in = new Intent(context, DialogActivity.class);
                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                in.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                context.startActivity(in);

            }
            if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
                //Device back to normal state (not in a call)
                Log.i("PHONESTATE","IDLE");

            }
        }
```

Can you please guide me on what should be the approach to achieve what i am trying to.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thanks Praveen for your suggestion!
The reason why the Dialog was not being displayed was that, i was trying to create the intent when i get an OFF_HOOK state in the phone listener. And the intent was being launched before the PhoneApp did.

The trick was to put a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` before starting the activity assuming the phone app will launch within 2 seconds from the time the phone state changes to OFF_HOOK;

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,DialogActivity.class);
intent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Tried this, still same result. :(
PS: I am trying to create the activity "DialogActivity" from a service which has a PhoneStateListener