# Prevent change of order of application presentation Android after intent service launch

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, intentservice

I have the following situation: One main application is the launcher **application (A)**, *always the application is running*, and this application call another a **child application (B)** fig 1 . The problem occurs when the application (A) launch an `intent service` and the application(B) use this intent (fig 2).

This is the code used to launch the intent service:

**Service**

```
intentCodeRead.putExtra(BARCODE_TEXT, readStr);
intentCodeRead.putExtra(BARCODE_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
intentCodeRead.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
sendBroadcast(intentCodeRead);
```

Any suggestion of flags to prevent this behaviour?
[image: figure 1 application A calling application B]

[image: figure 2 application B changing context with A]

**EDIT 1**

In the **application (A)**( The launcher application) I have an `intentService` that made a `broadcast` to another applications. The **application (B)** is an application that listen to this broadcast. When (A) make a broadcast the **application (B)** listen then. The problem is that **(A)** bring to front of **(B)** when **(A)** do this broadcast. How can I made a `broadcast` without change the order of applications presentation?

**EDIT 2**

**application A**

*BarcodeScannerService.java*

```
intentCodeRead.putExtra(Constants.BARCODE_TEXT, readStr);
intentCodeRead.putExtra(Constants.BARCODE_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());
intentCodeRead.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);               
sendBroadcast(intentCodeRead);
```

*initservice.java*

```
Intent intentService = new Intent(context, BarcodeScannerService.class);
context.startService(intentService);
```

**application B**

*receive.java*

```
BroadcastReceiver actionBarcodeScannerAndPresenceReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            /*  Receiver for the barcode scan and presence sensor events    */

                if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION_PRESENCE)) {
                    try
                    {
                        Log.e("Sensor Presenca","Detectada");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocorreu um erro no sensor de presença", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION_ON_BARCODE)) {
                    try {
                        String scannedText = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.BARCODE_TEXT);

                        if(scannedText.equals("0123456789"))
                        {
                            barcodeResult.setText(scannedText);
                            barcodeResult.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                            //Thread.sleep(5000);
                            ReturnResult("BARCODE", 0);
                        }else{
                            barcodeResult.setText(scannedText);
                            barcodeResult.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                           //Thread.sleep(5000);
                            ReturnResult("BARCODE", 1);
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocorreu um erro ao ler o código de barras!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
```

This code works well.The only problem is, always when **(A)** send the `broadcast` message the application **(A)** bring to front of **(B)**. What is the flags or methods to prevent this?

Comment: Can you clarify the question?

Comment: What is the order of application presentation?

Comment: The order of presentation is: the first app that is showed is (A) this app is the launch app. After 10s the application (B) is called by the (A). The (B) application use a service from a class intentService from (A) through a sendBroadcast. The broadcast are received sucessfully by the (B) application, but the problems is the application (A) goes to the front presentation covering the (B) aplication.

Comment: @Shmuel look to post update please.

Comment: Post some code for more understanding.

Comment: @PravinDivraniya , I insert portions of interest of the code.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev Updated the order of presentation, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My workaround for this problem was use `ActivityManager` to bring to front the application that the `broadcast` activity send to background. The following code was used and was adapted from [Android, how to bring a Task to the foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919616/android-how-to-bring-a-task-to-the-foreground/18197545#18197545)

```
ActivityManager am  = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++)
{
    if (!recentTasks.get(i).baseActivity.toShortString().contains("your_class_to_be_avoid")) {
        activityManager.moveTaskToFront(recentTasks.get(i).id, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);
    }
}
```

In this code I'm send to foreground every application that is different to my main application.